# Replacing the mscomctl.ocx version with a previous one (only for test)

Tags: excel

I have the mscomctl.ocx version 6.1.98.34 (06-06-2012) on my Win8 computer. I get this file installed on my computer through the installation of Office 2010.

I am wondering if it is technically possible to install a previous version of this file on my computer? Why? To **test** the version of this file from my client's computer.

I already try to replace my version with the other one (unregister + copy/paste + register with elevated privilege) but it doesn't work. So I suspect there is something I ignore (like dependencies or something else).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the file, override it: Put a copy of the file in the application directory. The application directory is searched before the system directory. That way your custom version affects only the application you are testing.

Comment: As far as I know, we can register only one version of the same OCX on a computer. Don't forget this is not simply a copy in a folder, this is also a registering of the component on the system (registry). Furthermore this is not really a problem with affecting others applications on my computer, no problem about that. The problem is that when I register another version of mscomctl.ocx (a more recent version from another computer) I got the succeed warning from regsvr32 but when I open Excel 2010, create a UserForm and drop a ListView on it I got an error. So I don't know if technically possible